# Cannot find java development kit files in specified path in VS2015

Tags: java, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have installed VS2015 and JDK9. when i'm trying to locate the jdk path in VS2015, it says like cannot find java development kit files in specified path.

Comment: maybe VS does not support java 9. The structure of the directories has been changed due to the introduction of the modular system.

Answer (score 0):

What do you see when you run : echo %JAVA_HOME% ?

Should be something like c:\someInstallPathTo\Java\jdk9

Comment: No. It is not returning the installed path. Then what i did wrong?

Comment: I have installed jdk 8. Now i can locate it in VS2015

Comment: Set your environment variable. 
Windows > Edit the system environment variables > New > JAVA_HOME = path to jdk... Open a new shell and try the echo %JAVA_HOME% again

Comment: I'm not familiar with the VS tool but maybe it has a setting in it for specifying where to find the jdk path as well.